# Can't generate apk (Android Studio)

Tags: android, apk

. . ok, i have looked around can not find a answer for my question.  When I try to generate an apk on android studio of my app, its just marked off basically, i can not click on generate apk, i can not click on the following buttons on "build", "Compile, Generate Apk, and Build Artifacts", please help.
I have looked on stackoverflow for a while now, and cant find an question/answer similar of mine.
The only thing that comes to mind, why its messing up, is. I am using some files i got off github, from an app sample to help me out. Thats it. I wouldnt think that would mess up the app. But maybe it did. 
Please help

Comment: Why don't you share/link to the code on Github that you are using - since you think it may be related to your problem?

Comment: here is a link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/ Its not on github, i thought it was. but i donwloaded the code from it, to help me out, and i just cant get a apk.